# Cakephp response cannot read UTF-8 file name

Tags: php, cakephp, utf-8, response

I want to download the file after login check so wrote a function in my controller like

```
// Function to check login and download News PDF file
public function download(){

    if($this->Auth->user()){ 
        // Get the news file path from newsId 
        $pNewsObj  = ClassRegistry::init('PublicNews');
        $news = $pNewsObj->findById($newsId);

        $filePath = ROOT.DS.APP_DIR.DS.'webroot/upload_news'.DS.$news['PublicNews']['reference'];
        // Check if file exists
        if(!file_exists($filePath)){
            return $this->redirect('/404/index.php');
        }
        $this->response->charset('UTF-8');
        //$this->response->type('pdf');
        $this->response->file('webroot/upload_news'.DS.$news['PublicNews']['reference'],  array('download' => true, 'name' => $news['PublicNews']['reference']));
        //$this->response->download($news['PublicNews']['reference']);
        return $this->response;
    }else{
        return $this->redirect(array('controller'=> 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
    }
}
```

Now, everything works fine as required.

PROBLEM : when the file name is in UTF-8 eg. テスト.pdf (its Test.pdf in japanese) cakephp throws error like this.

[image]

For English filename it works perfectly fine but my client wants the filename should be the same as uploaded, so I can't change the filename to English.

Comment: Windows or Linux? If the former, I'm afraid that PHP does not use the Windows APIs that allow multi-byte file names.

Comment: Its a Linux machine.

Comment: Can you check if another encoding works for japanese? If yes, maybe you can check (somehow) encode type and save it in db as well.

Comment: @ArchLicher Thank you for reply. I checked with Shift-JIS but still no result.

Comment: can you try in your php.ini if you have mbstring extension enabled and how it can help you?

Comment: This simply means the byte-sequence you are using as the filename does not match the _actual_ filename. check the actual bytes in `$news['PublicNews']['reference']` and compare to the actual bytes for the file that exists in `webroot/upload_news` - note that it's a bit silly to serve via php a file that is actually public (you could e.g. just redirect to it).

Comment: @AD7six Thanks for the reply. I first thought of redirection but I can't make the download URL publicily available. That is the sole reason of using CakePHP response. Also, can you tell me how to checkthe byte-sequence of filename practically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know character encoding, you can use `mb_detect_encoding()` function if input text has enough length to detect encoding.
But I am guessing your client would upload SJIS file. Because most Japanese people are using SJIS, as Windows has adopted SJIS for Japanese language.

I confirmed your code in my local environment. As cake's `File` class seems to be not able to handle SJIS correctly, you cannot use `Response::file()`. So I wrote alternative code.

```
public function download(){

    if($this->Auth->user()){ 
        // Get the news file path from newsId 
        $pNewsObj  = ClassRegistry::init('PublicNews');
        $news = $pNewsObj->findById($newsId);

        if (!$news) {
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }

        $fileName = mb_convert_encoding($news['PublicNews']['reference'], 'SJIS-win', 'UTF8');

        // Directory traversal protection
        if (strpos($fileName, '..') !== false) {
            throw new ForbiddenException();
        }

        $filePath = WWW_ROOT . 'upload_news' . DS . $fileName;
        if (!is_readable($filePath)) {
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }

        if (function_exists('mime_content_type')) {
            $type = mime_content_type($filePath);
            $this->response->type( $type );
        } else {
            // TODO: If Finfo extension is not loaded, you need to detect content type here;
        }

        $this->response->download( $fileName );
        $this->response->body( file_get_contents($filePath) );

        return $this->response;
    }else{
        return $this->redirect(array('controller'=> 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
    }
}
```

However, I recommend you to convert SJIS to UTF8 before save it into your database and your disk. It is difficult to handle SJIS characters without enough knowledge about it. Because SJIS characters may contain ascii characters in the second byte. Especially backslash (\) is most dangerous. For example, 表 (955C) contains a backslash (5C = backslash). Note that I am not talking about rare cases. 表 means table or appearance in Japanese. 十 also contains a backslash and it means 10 in Japanese. 能 also contains a backslash and it means skill.

Unlike UTF-8 byte sequence, if you handle SJIS characters, almost all string functions don't work correctly. `explode()` would break SJIS byte sequence. `strpos()` would return wrong result.
Does your client connect to your server by using FTP or SCP directly? If not, it would be better to convert SJIS to UTF-8 before save, and re-convert UTF-8 to SJIS before return to your client.

Comment: By the way, it is not related with this question directly, but I think you shouldn't store uploaded files under the document root. Otherwise, accessing the URL of file directly, anyone would be able to download the file without login. I don't think such a behavior is desired from your client.

Comment: Kuritaさんagreed, better use http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#streaming-resources

Comment: @KuritaTakashi not if you put `deny from all` in .htaccess may be?

Comment: prats1411さん :) @noc2spamツ It's okay as well.

Comment: @KuritaTakashiさんありがとうございました。Thank you very much. It worked perfectly :) But one more thing missing, that is the file name. It displayes the ID as page title.

Answer (score 0):

If you like you can change the file name before uploading the file so at time of downloading this error will not happen.

```
    public function change_file_name($fileName= '') {
        $ext            =   pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $fileName       =   'file_'.time().".".$ext;
        $exFileName     =   strtolower(substr($fileName,strrpos($fileName,".") + 1));
        $sampleFileName =   str_replace('.'.$exFileName,'', $fileName);
        $name           =   Sanitize::paranoid($sampleFileName,array('_'));
        $fileRename     =   $name.'.'.$exFileName;
        return $fileRename;
    }
```

Call this function before uploading the file

```
    $return_file_name   =     $this->change_file_name($file_name);
    if($this->moveUploadedFile($tmp_name,WEBSITE_PROFILE_ROOT_PATH.$return_file_name)){
        $saveData['profile_image']          =   $return_file_name;
    }
```

I know this is not proper answer for your case.For this you can make a function like this which will fetch data from database and automatic rename all your save file and update it in your database

Answer (score 0):

Some more information about your client's specifications would help greatly, but [Tom Scott](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GsyhGHUEt-k) found base64 to be the simplest method of making Unicode characters work correctly in PHP.

Depending on how crucial the preservation of filenames in storage is, a solution could be to encode the filenames in base64 when files are uploaded, and reverse the encoding on download. You can then know that you are dealing with ASCII, which should be much more likely to work correctly.

You may need to replace **/** characters with **%2F** to make it work.

Hope this helps,
Issa Chanzi